# rs.next() not returning first value of the table

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, jdbc-odbc

If I am running the following piece of code rs.next should return values starting from the first row of the table instead its returning the values from second row.

```
        String val = "select bl.book_id,bl.branch_id, bl.card_no,bl.date_out, bl.due_date ,concat(b.fname,' ',b.lname) as borrower from book_loans bl inner join borrower b on bl.card_no=b.card_no where bl.book_id like '%"+lm.getBook_id()+"%' and bl.card_no like '%"+lm.getCard()+"%'";
            rs=st.executeQuery(val);
            if(rs.next())
            {
                for(int a=0;rs.next();a++)
                {   
                    System.out.println("hello# "+a);
                    lm.book_ids.add(rs.getString(1));
                    lm.branch_id.add(rs.getInt(2));
                    lm.cards.add(rs.getString(3));
                    lm.date_out.add(rs.getString(4));
                    lm.due_date.add(rs.getString(5));
                }
                for(int a=0;a<lm.branch_id.size();a++)
                {
                    System.out.println(lm.book_ids.get(a));
                    System.out.println(lm.branch_id.get(a));
                    System.out.println(lm.cards.get(a));
                    System.out.println(lm.date_out.get(a));
                    System.out.println(lm.due_date.get(a));
                }
                return 1;
            }
            return 2;
```

I am running the exact query in MySQL and its giving the proper value but its not in this code. Its showing in sql

## Book ID Branch ID Card No Date Out Due Date

72127317 1 9009 2013-11-25 2013-12-09

72127317 3 9009 2013-11-25 2013-12-09

and in here its retuning as follows

hello# 0
72127317
3
9009
2013-11-25
2013-12-09

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is here

```
if(rs.next()) // get the first record
{
for(int a=0;rs.next();a++) // get the second (and later) records....
```

You could use a `do while` loop like this instead -

```
int a = 0;
do 
{   
  System.out.println("hello# "+a);
  lm.book_ids.add(rs.getString(1));
  lm.branch_id.add(rs.getInt(2));
  lm.cards.add(rs.getString(3));
  lm.date_out.add(rs.getString(4));
  lm.due_date.add(rs.getString(5));
  a++;
} while (rs.next());
```

Comment: Perfect! it worked.. thanks. However the same thing was working in a different place. I don't know why not here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in for clause also .
You may try

```
  int a = 0;
    while (rs.next()){
        System.out.println("hello# "+a);
        lm.book_ids.add(rs.getString(1));
        lm.branch_id.add(rs.getInt(2));
        lm.cards.add(rs.getString(3));
        lm.date_out.add(rs.getString(4));
        lm.due_date.add(rs.getString(5));
        a++; 

  }
```

do ... while clause may cause nullPoint Exception.[ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)
And you need to add order by to you sql.

Comment: do.. while worked perfectly and also did not have to bother with query as well

Comment: When the ResultSet is null do... while may not work so perfectly.Using while ... dosen't bother with if(rs.next)